# Can the verb "solve" be applied to the noun "challenge"?

Tags: verbs, word-usage

For example, "John was asked to solve a complex challenge."

I find this to read very awkwardly, as if someone told me they solved a banana.  Is this a case of verb-noun mismatch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So long as the noun is something solvable, this would be a valid construction.  Thus puzzles, Rubik's cubes and equations are all nouns which can be the object of the verb "to solve".  So if the challenge was a puzzle, it could be solved.  If the challenge was, however, physical in nature, it would be more natural to say that the challenge was completed.  The answer to your question is thus "it depends on the nature of the challenge in question - if the challenge can be said to have a solution, it is acceptable to use the verb 'solve'".

Comment: Even if the noun is not something solvable, it would be a valid construction, though nonsensical. One can certainly write that ?"John was asked to solve a complex banana". There is no verb-noun mismatch. An example of verb-noun mismatch is *"John was asked to solve a complex bananas". Incidentally, as "solve" can mean "dissolve" there is actually nothing nonsensical about solving a banana. The problem is more practical: how to coagulate the banana.

Comment: I assume that usage is either technical or archaic.  Most people would not understand what you meant if you said that you were going to solve a banana.  The phrase may be grammatically correct, but our goal on EL+U is as much to explain how to communicate as it is to understand grammar.  In context a banana could be solvable (a combination banana?), but the point is that some challenges are solvable in a sense that people would commonly understand, both grammatically and logically.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that it is awkward, and stylistically inadvisable. Problems are 'solved,' while challenges are 'met,' or 'overcome.'

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage, a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts. Elizabeth M. while your answer is fitting, this site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective and could be improved by adding [references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/59/77227).

Answer (score 1):

The services company Halliburton's trademarked strap-line is "Solving challenges". I share the original questioner's queasiness with this but I suspect that the elasticity of English  probably allows it.

Answer (score 0):

"Solving a challenge" may not be linguistically correct. but it seems to be on the rise in a business or technical context (where "overcome a challenge" would sound slightly esoteric. An example I found is the  Solve initiative initiated by the MIT (Massachusetts Institute of Technology) https://solve.mit.edu/challenges.

Comment: Actually I don't finding "solving a challenge" on this page.  The page is called "Solve" and _solutions are submitted_.  The page presents various problems to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I am just confronting this in an article I am editing, and have opted for "find solutions to ... challenges".
"Find a solution to the challenge" seems to be very widely used (more than 1.5 million hits on Google).

Comment: Google hit count [is not accurate](https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2672285?hl=en). I get three pages of results when I search.